# How to define an Object using inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I have a small problem with a task which was given to us for a preparation for my exam:

In the UML you see the classes. I have to define class `Student`.
The Constructor I have to define looks like this:
The class Students inherits from interface `Immatrikulation` and class `person`.
Also there is a struct for `Adresse`
In `Adresse` you can find the string `ort` (which I have to use in the Constructor) and in "Adresse" you have the string `name`(also needed)

```
Student(const string& name, const string& ort, int matrikelnr);
```

I know how I can access and save data for matrikelnr, since I have the variable in the same class, but i don't know how I can define `ort` and `name` for student.

[UML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jiVY.png)

Comment: All questions on stackoverflow.com must include all pertinent information in the question itself, ***as plain text***. Suspicious links to dodgy external web sites, or images, that can stop working at any time rendering the question meaningless, are not acceptable. Please [edit] your question, remove all links to external images, and include all relevant information as plain text.

Comment: Also please translate the german variables (or annotate them with the english translation) so other people can understand what relationships you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call the base class constructor. Following your UML:

```
class Student : public Person {
public:
    Student(const string& name, const string& ort, int matrikeInr) : 
        Person(name, ort), matrikeINr(matrikeInr)
    { }
    // etc...
private:
    int matrikeINr;
};
```

Comment: Thank you, Igor! 
But if  I have an Object of student: 
``Student S = new Student("Bsp","Ort","5");``
How can I access for example Ort?

Comment: @Joana According to your UML diagram, you can access it like this: `s->getAddresse().ort` -- assuming that `ort` is a public memeber of `Addresse`.